# Move one directory of files into another while maintaining directory structure

Tags: linux, file-management

On Linux, I have directory #1, for example:

```
/foo/file (edited)
/foo/bar/foo/file6 (edited)
```

And directory #2, which may contain some of the same files:

```
/foo/file
/foo/file2
/foo/bar/file3
/foo/bar/file4
/foo/bar/foo/file5
/foo/bar/foo/file6
```

I'd like to move directory #1's files into directory #2 and if they exist, overwrite them. So we'd end up with:

```
/foo/file (edited)
/foo/file2
/foo/bar/file3
/foo/bar/file4
/foo/bar/foo/file5
/foo/bar/foo/file6 (edited)
```

`(edited)` denotes that the file is newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways I can think of:

```
cd /directory/one && tar cf - . | (cd /directory/two && tar xf - )
```

or

```
rsync -av /directory/one /directory/two
```

Comment: Since they mentioned Linux, you can assume gnu tar, which has -C for 'chdir': tar -C /directory/one  -cf - . | tar -C /directory/two -xvf -